# XSLT transformation of DXL not working

Tags: xml, xslt, ibm-doors

I have the following DXL (i.e. Lotus Notes XML data):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='6.5' maintenanceversion='4.0'>
    <noteinfo>
        <created><datetime>20020225T160055,64-05</datetime></created>
    <updatedby><name>CN=John Doe/O=MyOrg</name></updatedby>
    </noteinfo>
 </document>
```

I am trying to transform the DXL into HTML using an XSLT stylesheet, but the resulting HTML does not contain any data elements. I have not previously worked with DXL data before, and my XSLT is a bit rusty, so I'm not sure what is the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Submission</h2>
                <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Create date:</td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="document/noteinfo[1]/created[1]/datetime[1]"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Updated by:</td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="updatedby[1]/name[1]"/></td>
                        </tr>             
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: The XSLT stylesheet specifies version 2.0, so I assumed that is what I was using. I'm using the OxygenXML tool and I have it configured to use Saxon EE 9.6.

Comment: Ah yes, I just noticed the 2.0 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source XML has a default namespace declared in it:

```
<document xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='6.5' maintenanceversion='4.0'>
```

This means you need to declare it and use it in your XPath within your stylesheet:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:my="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">
```

You'll then need to reference it in your XPath within your XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="my:document/my:noteinfo[1]/my:created[1]/my:datetime[1]"/>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0 you can specify `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.lotus.com/dxl"` in the stylesheet section.

Here's my attempt, using a namespace declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" xmlns:my="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Submission</h2>
                <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Create date:</td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="my:document/my:noteinfo[1]/my:created[1]/my:datetime[1]"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Updated by:</td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="my:document/my:noteinfo[1]/my:updatedby[1]/my:name[1]"/></td>
                        </tr>             
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your XPath for the `Updated by` cell was incorrect, so I've made my own correction on that to get the value out of your sample XML.